# How do I fire a function immediately after another function is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<script>
function refreshChat() {
    var id = "'.$convers_id.'";
    var receiver = "'.$system->getFirstName($second_user->full_name).'";
    $.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/refreshChat.php?id="+id+"&receiver="+receiver, function(data) {
        $(".conversation-content").html(data);
    });
    var scroller = $(".conversation-message-list").getNiceScroll(0);
    $(".conversation-message-list").getNiceScroll(0).doScrollTop($(".conversation-content").height(),-1); 
}
window.setInterval(function(){
    refreshChat();
}, 2000);

function sendMessage() {
    var user2 = "'.$user2.'";
    var message = $("#message");
    if(message.val() != "" && message.val() != " ") {
        $.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/sendMessage.php?id="+user2+"&msg="+encodeURIComponent(message.val()), function(data) {
        $(".conversation-content").html(data);
            message.val("");
        });
    }
}
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        sendMessage();
    }
});
</script>
```

Right now, the refreshChat function calls an ajax script every 2 seconds. When you have entered a message and press enter, it calls a different ajax script. What I would like it to do, is call both functions at the same time. So the script calls the sendMessage function first and refreshes afterwards.

How can I do this? I have already tried changing it to:

```
<script>
function refreshChat() {
    var id = "'.$convers_id.'";
    var receiver = "'.$system->getFirstName($second_user->full_name).'";
    $.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/refreshChat.php?id="+id+"&receiver="+receiver, function(data) {
        $(".conversation-content").html(data);
    });
    var scroller = $(".conversation-message-list").getNiceScroll(0);
    $(".conversation-message-list").getNiceScroll(0).doScrollTop($(".conversation-content").height(),-1); 
}

function sendMessage() {
    var user2 = "'.$user2.'";
    var message = $("#message");
    if(message.val() != "" && message.val() != " ") {
        $.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/sendMessage.php?id="+user2+"&msg="+encodeURIComponent(message.val()), function(data) {
            $(".conversation-content").html(data);
            message.val("");
        });
    }
}
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        sendMessage();refreshChat();
    }
});
</script>
```

But this only enters the message first, and it only refreshes on the second keypress (enter). I would like to thank everybody beforehand on helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an illusion. Both functions *are* being called, but the chat window is refreshing *before* the chat message is able to save them.

To fix this, you should refresh the chat window only once the new message has been successfully saved:

```
function refreshChat() {
    // Removed for brevity
}

function sendMessage() {
    var user2 = "'.$user2.'";
    var message = $("#message");
    if(message.val() != "" && message.val() != " ") {
        $.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/sendMessage.php?id="+user2+"&msg="+encodeURIComponent(message.val()), function(data) {
            $(".conversation-content").html(data);
            message.val("");

            // Now, this will only be called once the ajax is complete
            refreshChat();
        });
    }
}

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        sendMessage();

        // I removed the refreshChat() call from here and moved it
        // into the $.get() callback above ^^
    }
});
```

As you can see, I moved your `refreshChat()` method to now be called from within the jQuery `$.get()` callback.

Comment: almost there... when i enter a message, it loads the previous message, so every time i enter a message, the previous one gets loaded in the screen

Comment: We've solved the initial problem, then. Glad I could help. With your follow-up problem, I suggest creating a new question on SO and providing more information specific to the new problem (such as your php script and returned `data`) so we can better assist you.

Comment: Alternatively, use promises: `$.get(...).done(refreshChat);`

Comment: Your edited script doesnt work. Your first script worked best, but it doesnt solve the problem...

Comment: @Aurora All I did in the latest edit was remove the contents of the `refreshChat` function for brevity. Did you also remove that code in your final script? I'm here to teach you code and help solve your problems, not write the specific code for you.

Comment: @WesFoster and i am here to learn. I wouldnt ask you to wite code for me. And please do not get me wrong, i am very thankfull for your help

Comment: @WesFoster and sorry for my mistake. Im a dutch girl who wants to learn how to code and i had no idea what brevity meant

Comment: @Aurora Learning something new every day! :) I'll look out for your follow-up question on Stack Overflow

Comment: @WesFoster Is there a way to pause the first function (the refreshchat) and then execute it after the sendmessage function has been executed?

Comment: That's what my example does. It uses the Ajax callback to delay the calling of refreshChat

Comment: @WesFoster i have edited your awnser to my sollution. I used a promises after the callback so it calls the ajax script twice. I will mark your awnser as correct after it has been reviewed. Thank you again for teaching me:)

Comment: @WesFoster considering what i asked, I marked your awnser as correct and i have added my own code underneath. Thank you again and i hope you have a great day!

Comment: @4castle Thank you too for suggesting using promises. It helped me solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using callbacks, that may be what you need?

Here is a link for reference.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Comment: I don't think they meant in parallel, because the wording they used later implied that they wanted it to happen in quick succession. "At the same time" in that they should be next to each other in the code.

Comment: @4castle you are right, it needs to happen in quick succession

Comment: Okay I have edited the answer to avoid further confusion with java script being paralel

Answer (score 0):

**MY WORKING AWNSER**

Considering for what i asked, i have marked Wes Foster's awnser as correct. What made it work for me is also applying a promises after the get function. This way, the ajax script get's called twice as needed. I hope it will help someone in the future. (Look at me... travelling through time...). You will find my code underneath:

```
function refreshChat() {
var id = "'.$convers_id.'";
var receiver = "'.$system->getFirstName($second_user->full_name).'";
$.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/refreshChat.php?id="+id+"&receiver="+receiver, function(data) {
    $(".conversation-content").html(data);
});
var scroller = $(".conversation-message-list").getNiceScroll(0);
$(".conversation-message-list").getNiceScroll(0).doScrollTop($(".conversation-content").height(),-1); 
}

function sendMessage() {
    var user2 = "'.$user2.'";
    var message = $("#message");
    if(message.val() != "" && message.val() != " ") {
        $.get("'.$system->getDomain().'/ajax/sendMessage.php?id="+user2+"&msg="+encodeURIComponent(message.val()), function(data) {
            $(".conversation-content").html(data);
            message.val("");


            refreshChat();
        }).done(refreshChat);
}
}
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        sendMessage();


    }
});
```